# SQL update if column data different on form submit data then update other ways not update

Tags: sql, database, forms

I Have a database Table Like this.

```
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| id |    title    |                post                   |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 01 | title 01    | Post Content Post Content Post Content|
| 02 | title 02    | Post Content Post Content Post Content|
| 03 | title 03    | Post Content Post Content Post Content|
| 04 | title 04    | Post Content Post Content Post Content|
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------+
```

and I have a update form for update tile and post field. I use sql query Like

```
UPDATE post 
SET title='{$_POST["title"]}',post='{$_POST["post"]}  
WHERE id={$_POST["id"]}';
```

Everything works good but it update all time of submit the edit form.

I want to edit database data only update title or post content on form submit with different data other ways no update on database.

How I check there are any different database data and submit form data and update my database data .

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can handle this in 2 ways -

1. Using a Before Update trigger on the table, and compare the old value with the new value before updating.
2. UPDATE post SET title='{$_POST["title"]}',post='{$_POST["post"]} WHERE id={$_POST["id"]}' AND (title != '{$_POST["title"]}' OR post !='{$_POST["post"]});

Comment: How I Use Before Update trigger on the table. PLEASE Demo or tutorial url **THANK U SO MUCH**

Comment: You can refer to the tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm

Comment: **THANKS** again for your response